# Extjs XTemplate three same level array loop

Tags: extjs

I want to loop over three arrays at the same time in my extjs code,but it does not work!
    I have been testing and the result with two arrays is ok, but **three arrays do not work**!

```
var json = {
    name : 'tom',
    rowTitleArr : ['1','2'],
    colTitleArr : ['a','b'],
    optionArr : ['x','y']
}
var tpl = [
    '{name}<br>',
    '<tpl for="rowTitleArr">',
        '--{.}<br>',
        '<tpl for="parent.colTitleArr">',
            '----{.}<br>',
            '<tpl for="parent.parent.optionArr">',
                '--------{.}<br>',
             '</tpl>',
        '</tpl>',
    '<tpl>'
];
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(tpl);
tpl.overwrite(panel.body,json);
```

the result is :
        tom
        --1
        ----a
        ----b
        --2
        ----a
        ----b
I think that is should be :
        --1
        ----a
        --------x
        --------y
        ----b
        --------x
        --------y
        --2
        ----a
        --------x
        --------y
        ----b
        --------x
        --------y
        ...
        why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I got this working was with your rowTitleArr as an object.

Your exmaple does not work because parent.parent is not known in the values. U can set it with a template exec function.

```
var data = {
        name: 'xxx',
        rowTitleArr: [{number:'1'},{number:'2'},{number:'3'}],
        colTitleArr: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        optionArr : ['x','y']
    };
    var tpl = [
        '{name}',
        '<br/>',
        '<tpl for="rowTitleArr">',
        '----{number}<br>',
        '<tpl exec="values.parent = parent;"></tpl>',
            '<tpl for="parent.colTitleArr">',
        '---------{.}<br>',                    
                    '<tpl for="parent.parent.optionArr">',
                '----------------{.}<br>',
             '</tpl>',
            '</tpl>',
        '</tpl>'];
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/2WEVE/1/

Comment: I have been made a test,
but result is still wrong!
please see my test result in my reply!
thank you!

Comment: You are right, the reason this is hard to do is because you're working  with arrays and you can't just call parent.parent. It might be easier if you prepare your data before you start with loops, or use some template functions.